# DocumentDB document link for Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.0, document-database

If I have an Azure Cosmos database with the following setup

Database name: MyDatabase

Collection: MyCollection

How would I use UriFactory to create a document link to use in CreateDocumentAsync(documentLink, document)?

I had a look at the Microsoft documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/)  but this seems to use a document id to delete the document, I want to create a document instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uri myUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("MyDatabase", "MyCollection");